# Can this code section "*, ::before, ::after { boxsizing: border-box }" work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am reading the book "CSS in Depth", Chapter 3，now I encounter a problem, that is the CSS codes here:

```
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In the book I read, it says these selectors will target all the elements and every pseudo-element on the page.

Then, I find that there is no selector before "::before" and "::after", while in MDN Web Doc(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), there are such discriptions:

> You can use only pseudo-element in a selector. It must appear after the simple selectors in the statement.

So I am confused that, are the codes above right? Or is it should be the codes like:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The full code list is [here](https://github.com/CSSInDepth/css-in-depth/blob/master/ch03/listing-3.6.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, both are correct.

The description from MDM contains one more word, that you've removed:

> You can use only ***one*** pseudo-element in a selector. It must appear after the simple selectors in the statement.

Which means that you can't use two pseudo-selectors in one css selection.
When we add part ,,It must appear after the simple selectors'' means that you can't chain them like that:

```css
selector::pseudo-element::pseudo-element {
}
```

But overall `::after` and `*::after` have the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks very much! Thanks for your correction and explaination. That is really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#universal-selector):

> If a universal selector represented by * (i.e. without a namespace prefix) i**s not the only component** of a sequence of simple selectors selectors or is immediately followed by a pseudo-element, then the * **may be omitted** and the **universal selector's presence implied.**